# Touchbar doesn’t work on MacBook Pro (14,2 2017) with Debian install

Tags: linux, debian, zsh, macbook-pro

I downloaded Debian 12 on my MacBook Pro (14,2 2017). I have tried the various reddit/form/blog post and instructions. I am really at my wits end trying to make this work. New to Linux but I know enough to run commands and troubleshoot.

Here are a list (Not Exhaustive) of sites I have tried or used to research:

- https://wiki.t2linux.org
- https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/mm7es8/what_linux_distros_are_compatible_with_the_newer/
- https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux
- https://medium.com/@journalehsan/how-i-installed-linux-on-my-macbook-2017-and-enjoyed-it-2056f92cc7df

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.